# Proving that a map is zero

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, functional-analysis

Let $A,B$ be two banach spaces and $\Omega, \nu, \Sigma$ a measure space. Consider the map $F \colon \Omega \to \mathcal L(A,B^*)$. If $F(\omega)(a)=0$ for all $a \in A$. then why does one need $A$ to be separable in order to deduce that $F(\omega)=0$?

So the complete setting would be that one wants to show that $F$ i suniequly determined by 
$$\int_\Omega \langle F f ,b \rangle \, d\nu$$
where $f$ is any integrable function and $b \in B$ chosen arbitrarily. So one takes another $\tilde F$ fulfilling the equality and chooses $f= \chi_E\, a$. then
$$\int_E \langle (F-\tilde F)a,b \rangle \, d\nu=0$$
for all $E \in \Sigma$, $a\in A$ and $b \in B$. Hence 
$$\langle (F-\tilde F)a,b \rangle=0$$ almost everywhere. No the author claims that one needs the existence of a countable norming set of B so that one can follow
$$(F-\tilde F)a=0$$
almost everywhere. then one needs that A is seperable to deduce that
$$F-\tilde F=0$$
almost everywhere. Which means $F=\tilde F$.

Comment: One doesn't. $L(a) = 0$ for all $a$ is precisely the definition of $L = 0$.

Comment: well that's what I thought but I am currently reading a book and it states that you need A to be separable... it also gave a freaking counter example..

Comment: I'd be very curious about that counterexample. Which book is that?

Comment: so I have simplfied the problem and I might have made a mistake there. it is dinculeanus monography "vector measures"

Comment: A mistake in the simplification is believable. Is the original setting representable in a short enough way?

Comment: hang on I'll add it in a sec

Comment: @ daniel fisher I have added the complete setting

Comment: Ah, we integrate. So in general we can't say much about the value at a point just from the vanishing of the integrals. Note that if $0 < \nu(\{\omega\}) < +\infty$, then we have the pointwise information and can conclude $F(\omega) = 0$ without any separability assumptions on $A$ and $B$. But that's an exceptional situation. Abstractly, the goal is to conclude that $F(\omega) = 0$ a.e. [$\nu$] follows from $\int_E F(\omega)\,d\nu = 0$ for all measurable $E$ with $\nu(E) < +\infty$. Banach-space valued integrals are delicate when the spaces aren't separable.

Comment: I've forgotten too much to see it at a glance, but it's credible that the separability assumptions are necessary (if we don't have assumptions on $\nu$ that make them unnecessary).

Comment: oh i see i probably have to use the continuity of the measure $\nu$. am I correct? but thanks you have already helped me  a lot :)